# how to get Jmeter test result from JAVA Class by using JMeter API

Tags: java, web-services, jmeter, jmx

I'm new to JMeter. I found the following code to run a JMeter test plan(.jmx) from JAVA project by using JMeter API StandardJMeterEngine.

*But how can I get the execution result as return?*

I saw many articles about SampleResult. If this is a solution, can you please provide details about how can I integrate my sampleResult into the existing JMeter test plan.

```
    // JMeter Engine
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("../jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("../apache-jmeter-2.11");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    SaveService.loadProperties();

    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("../Integ.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    in.close();
    // Run JMeter Test
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();

    <how to capture result here?????????????????>
    jmeter.exit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following lines before `jmeter.run()` stanza:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");//$NON-NLS-1$
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}

String logFile = "/path/to/output/file.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

The results will be going to `/path/to/output/file.jtl` file. Which can be opened after test execution via listener of your choice in JMeter GUI.

You can control what values to store via `user.properties` file. As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide recommended values are:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But by this way, we get result output to file. If I want to do analysis on it. I have to read it back into Java. 1) Is there any way to get the response directly from JAVA? 2) Is there any way to run one specific test case in the testPlanTree? Please help with with.

Comment: For response analysis via Java code I would go for i.e. Beanshell or JSR223 Post Processor. What do you mean by "specific test case"? If it's thread group - you can set other thread groups thread numbers to 0. If it is a single sampler - you can put it (or remaining) under IF Controller.

Comment: It is thread group. In the .jmx, we have 17 thred groups named by Q1-Q17. If I want to run one specific thread group, what should I do. Can you please provide details about how to set other groups numbers to 0 in java project instead of changing it in JMeter UI?

Comment: this way will be more clear. My core question will be how to get individual thread group from a .JMX test plan tree. After this, I should be able to continue on one thread instead of the entire .JMX tree.

Comment: In that case you can read original JMX file into a hashtree, remove elements which are not needed (in case of "not interesting" tread groups you can set thread number to zero and the thread group won't execute), configure JMeter engine to use updated hashtree and run the test.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access the test results directly in Java without the workaround via file output, you can redefine the result collector and get notified for each sample event:

```
public class MyResultCollector extends ResultCollector {

    public MyResultCollector(Summariser summer) {
        super(summer);
    }

    @Override
    public void sampleOccurred(SampleEvent e) {
        super.sampleOccurred(e);
        SampleResult r = e.getResult();
        if (r.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println("Response time in milliseconds: " + r.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, your plan woukd contain a View Results Tree that mentions a file.

Jmeter Would write results there.